# Angular 4 Click $event with Extra Parameters

Tags: angular

Is it possible to capture the $event parameter on a click event and also pass in some extra parameter data to a component method?

Example template:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of data" (click)="onItemClick($event, item)">
    {{ item.Name }}
</div>
```

Example component:

```
onItemClick(event, item) {
    // do something
}
```

Comment: Yes you can. Have you tested?

Comment: I did and it wasn't working for me.  I must have messed something up.  I'll give it another try.  Thanks!

Answer (score 43):

Yes it would work fine. But keep the order of parameters same.

```
<div *ngFor="let item of data" (click)="onItemClick($event, item)">
```

In this case the second element is your passed element.

```
onItemClick(event, item)
{
  console.log("Checking passed item: ",item);
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Yes It will work fine. Put console.log inside the function and check.

```
onItemClick(event, item)
{
  console.log("Event: ",event,"Item: ",item);
}
```